# Prove that if $\nu(A)=\int_A fd\mu$ and $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite, then $\nu$ is $\sigma$-finite.

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\nu$ be the measure defined on a $\sigma$ finite measure space with measure $\mu$ and a non negative, measurable, real valued function $f$ such that $\nu=f*\mu$ so that $\nu(A)=\int_Afd\mu$.I know that $\nu$ is a measure. My attempt has been to construct a nested sequence of measurable sets $A_i$ so that $A_i\subset A_{i+1}$ and $\Sigma_{i\in \mathbb{N}}=\Omega$. Now because $\mu$ is $\sigma$- measurable $\mu(A_i)<\infty$ $\forall A_i$. Now if $\nu(A_N)=\infty$ it follows from the linearity of the integral that $\nu(A_{i>N})=\infty$. However I haven't been able to produce a contradiction from this assumption.

Comment: Try approximating $f$ with simple functions for a given set $A_i$ from the sequence

Comment: @crystal_math $f|_{A_i}$=$\Sigma_{n<N}$a(n) $1_{E_n}$ now $\int_{A_i}$$f$=$\Sigma_{n<N}$a(n) $\mu$({E_n}) and since $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite the Integral must also be finite.

Answer (score 3):

What you have written is in general wrong with the current assumptions. Consider the measure space $(\mathbb{R}.\mathcal{B},\lambda)$ the standard measure space on the reals with the Lebesgue measure. Then consider
$$f=\begin{cases} \frac{1}{x} & \text{for }  x>0 \\ 
0 & \text{for } x \leq0 
\end{cases},$$
which satisfies your assumptions on $f$.
Then by monotonicity of the integral $$\nu((-1,1))=\int_0^1 fd\lambda \geq \sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^n \int_{2^{-n-1}}^{2^{-n}}d\lambda = \frac12+\frac12+\frac12+\dots = \infty,$$ and due to the nesting propert of $\sigma$-finite measures there exists a large enough $N$ such that $(-1,1) \subset A_N$ and by monotonicity of measures $\nu(A_n)=\infty \quad \forall n\geq N$,
hence $\nu$ can't possibly be sigma finite.

Comment: 1/x $\times1_{(0,\infty]}$ is not bounded so f is not Riemann integral.

Comment: are we not talking about the Lebesgue integral? What over conditions do you have on $f$?

Comment: Yes we are but you evaluated the Lebesgue integral with the Riemann integral. The conditions, that both integrals are the same  are not met with the function you proposed. Hence your reasoning, that $\nu$ cannot be $\sigma$-finite is wrong.

Comment: Right I see what you're getting at. When the function like the one I used is sufficiently nice we don't really need to worry about this. But I'll edit my answer to show that the integral is still infinite.

Comment: Why is does the inequality hold?

Comment: The best answer to that question is draw a picture. Notice the simple function whose integral is the right hand side of the inequality is less than or equal to $\frac1x$. i.e. on the interval $[2^{-n-1},2^{-n}]$ the following inequality holds $\frac1x \geq 2^n$

Comment: This indeed seems to be a counter example, I will mail my Prof and ask her about it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sadly this is not correct, There does exist a a nested sequence of sets, where each set has measure less than $\infty$. Namely $A_n$=$mathbb{R}\(-1/n,1/n), i.e. the Real numbers without the Ball of radius 1/n around 0.

Comment: Yes I see. I will ponder on this further. Note however, $A_n$ does not have finite measure but that is easily fixed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118672/discussion-between-milos-tasic-and-robert).

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, but the following was what I had in mind when I suggested to approximate $f$ with simple functions.

Let $E_n$ be the sequences of sets through which $\mu$ is $\sigma$ finite.

If $f=\chi_A$, then $v(E_n)<\infty $. Now if $v_1$ and $v_2$ are $\sigma$ finite measures (with sequences $I_n$ and $J_m$), then $v_1+v_2$ is a $\sigma$ finite measure as well:

$$(v_1+v_2)(I_n\cap J_m)<\infty$$

and $$\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcup_{m=1}^{\infty} I_n \cap J_n = X$$

It doesn't take much to conclude that linear combinations of $\sigma$ finite measures is also a $\sigma$ finite measure. Let $s_n$ be a simple function such that $|\int f - s_n|<\epsilon$,  then $$\int f <\int s_n +\epsilon$$

Notice that, $\int s_n = s_n * \mu$ and $s_n$ is a linear combination of characteristic functions. So $s_n * \mu$ is a $\sigma$ finite measure for some sequence of sets $F_n$. As a result, $\int f$ is a sigma finite measure for some sequence of sets $F_n$.